# Setter and getter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, getter-setter

I find myself practicing the **get** and **set** properties Javascript.

My output (below) is not showing the new breed for gato1 nor the new color for gato2 when I change it.

But if I call the property `gato1.getRaza` or `gato2.getColor`, it returns the value already changed.

```
class Animal{
    constructor (clase,especie,color){
        this.clase = clase;
        this.especie = especie;
        this.color = color;
        this.info = `El ${this.especie}, es un animal ${this.clase} de color ${this.color}`;
    }
    verInfo(){
        document.write(`<label class="animals">${this.info}</label><br><br><br>`);
    }
    set setColor(color){
        this.color = color;
    }
    get getColor(){
        return this.color;
    }
}

class Gato extends Animal{
    constructor(clase,especie,color,raza){
        super(clase,especie,color);
        this.raza = raza;
        this.info += `, además es de raza ${this.raza}`;
    }
    set setRaza(newRaza){
        this.raza = newRaza;
    }
    get getRaza(){
        return this.raza;
    }
    maullar(){
        document.write(`<label class="animals__cat">El ${this.especie} 
        hace "Miau"</label><br><br><br>`);
    }
}

const gato1 = new Gato(`terrestre`,`Gato`,`blanco`,`andro`); 
// created a gato1 object of the Cat class, inherited from the Animal class

const gato2 = new Animal(`terrestre`,`Gato`,`gris`);
// create a gato2 object of the Animal class

gato1.verInfo(); 
// I see current information from gato1

gato1.maullar(); 
//I run the maullar() method to show that only the gato1 of the Cat class can effectively meow

gato1.setRaza = `angora`; 
// here I apply the property set to change the property race of the gato1

gato1.verInfo(); 
/*I call again the method verInfo() to observe that the breed for which the 
gato1 object was previously entered has been changed*/

gato2.verInfo();
// I call gato2 to see their properties

gato2.setColor = `negro`;
// changed its color

gato2.verInfo();
// I show again its properties where it is supposed to have changed its color
```

Output:

- El Gato, es un animal terrestre de color blanco, además es de raza andro
- El Gato hace "Miau"
- El Gato, es un animal terrestre de color blanco, además es de raza ***andro*** <-- here
- El Gato, es un animal terrestre de color gris
- El Gato, es un animal terrestre de color ***gris*** <--- here

Comment: `this.info` is only computed **once** in the constructor. If you want the latest values to be reflected in `verInfo` you'll need to recompute the value of `this.info` (either in the setters so that it's always up to date, or in `verInfo` itself if you want to only compute it when you need it).

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! This is a great question. I edited it to move the problem to the top. Continue like this and happy learning JS :)

Comment: Aside: Why are you using `document.write`? There are very few reasons why you should ever do that! Just use `console.log()`

Comment: Your `info` should be a `getter` since it's the one that depends on dynamic data.

Comment: Having a getter in JS called get `getRaza` doesn't make any sense, it should just be named `raza` . Same applies to `setRaza` it should just be `get raza`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `info` property should be a getter since it's the one that depends on other data.

This is a better approach than what was suggested by [Fastnlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74145710/227299) since it doesn't require updating `info` from multiple places and doesn't add duplication.

However, as an aside, your getters and setters include `get` and `set` in their names. That makes for funny code like `b = a.getProp` and `a.setProp = 1`, instead of `b = a.prop` and `a.prop = 1` which is the intention of getters and setters. Notice how much cleaner the above looks. Also, getters and setters that do nothing are useless and not required in JS since you can always change it to a getter later without updating its interface.

```js
class Animal{
    constructor (clase, especie, color){
        this.clase = clase;
        this.especie = especie;
        this.color = color;
    }
   
    get info() {
       return `El ${this.especie}, es un animal ${this.clase} de color ${this.color}`
    }
}

class Gato extends Animal{
    constructor(clase, especie, color, raza){
        super(clase, especie, color);
        this.raza = raza;
    }
    get info() {
        return super.info + `, además es de raza ${this.raza}`;
    }

}

const gato = new Gato(`terrestre`,`Gato`,`blanco`,`andro`); 
const animal = new Animal(`terrestre`,`Animal`,`gris`);

console.log({gato: gato.info, animal: animal.info}); 

gato.raza = `angora`; 
animal.color = `negro`;

console.log({gato: gato.info, animal: animal.info});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not updating the `info` property when you change the `color` or `raza` properties.
You can do it like this:

```js
set setColor(color){
    this.color = color;
    this.info = `El ${this.especie}, es un animal ${this.clase} de color ${this.color}`;
}
```

```js
set setRaza(newRaza){
    this.raza = newRaza;
    this.info = `El ${this.especie}, es un animal ${this.clase} de color ${this.color}, además es de raza ${this.raza}`;
}
```

Comment: Duplicating that line into multiple setters is a bad way of doing it.

Comment: Many thanks to all for your contribution!! I managed to solve the problem, a greeting to all!!

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74145979/227299 which is a solution that avoids the duplication making this way simpler and provides better practices for using getters and setters

Comment: This is actually wrong! It's not just hard to maintain. You'd have to change `setColor` to update in both the base and the extended class with slightly different behaviors, which means you're likely doing it wrong. As it stands, if you call `gato.setColor()` it will mess up the behavior of `this.info` for cats, since it won't contain the `raza` information. Consider deleting this answer.